# Splitting GraphQL data with react-string-replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using GraphQL and

```
const itineraryTabItems= get(this.props,'data.contentfulTourInformation.itineraryTabItems')
```

I get returned **JSON** array of

```
["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7"]
```

this is a screenshot of it logged in the console
[image]

then with `<ul>{itineraryTabItems}</ul>` I get the following HTML returned in the project

```
<ul>Item1Item2Item3Item4Item5Item6Item7</ul>
```

How can I split these to the following?

```
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
<li>Item3</li>
<li>Item4</li>
<li>Item5</li>
<li>Item6</li>
<li>Item7</li>
```

I tried doing this by installing `react-string-replace` and this code

```
<ul className="default itinerary">
  {reactStringReplace(itineraryTabItems,  /","/g, (match, i) => (
    <li key={i}>{match}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: If itineraryTabItems is a string, then note that its separators are a comma *followed by a space*, not just a comma. (or is it an array?)

Comment: It is an array.

Comment: Then it probably won't work when used directly with `reactStringReplace`, because as the name indicates, it works with *strings*. (did you try converting the array to a string first and see what happened?)

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance. I was originally trying to do it this way, rather than via mapping the array as there are more elements that I wanted replace within each array item. I think the best way is to do in several parts as you suggest. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont you just want to map the array out to LIs?

something like this:

```
<ul>
  {itineraryTabItems.map(i=><li>{i}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Deets on arrays in react has a UL->LI as one of the examples https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html